# How can I use PCA to determine spread ratios for multiple legs?

Tags: principal-components, optimal-hedge-ratio

I would like to generalize Paul Teetor's [**A Better Hedge Ratio**](http://quanttrader.info/public/betterHedgeRatios.pdf), which uses prcomp() to determine a ratio between two legs. I am hoping to extend this to multiple legs, but am having trouble finding accurate results. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of N components:

1. compute the NxN covariance matrix
2. compute the N eiggenvectors and take the one that has the signs that you want
3. the weights of this eiggen vector corresponds to the basket of N components that you wish to create